# Mac Outlook 2011 pasting text not at cursor

Tags: mac, email, ms-office

I'm using outlook for emails, each time I paste copied/cut text (from within the same email) it will not paste at the the cursor/ibar but at the top of the email text.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just tried to replicate your problem and could not. Please type some generic text (for privacy) and show us a screen shot. I have the suspicion you cursor is just siting there, not blinking? It did happen to me, so i make sure the cursor is where it suposed to be (and blinking)

Comment: Wouldn't you know...can't re-create the problem. Thanks for the suggestions Borderline .. nope, cursor was flashing when it happened and in the place I needed it. Will do some more digging and re-create if I can.

Comment: OK the plot thickens...

Comment: I re-created the same steps as the original email.

I use an automator script and keyboard shortcut to attach pdfs to emails since I've not been able to find a way to change the default email programme that OSX uses for the 'attach to email'. (This was created using the Apple automator and an Outlook library). It seems that when the resulting email is edited the paste function is upset as described above.

I think this answers the initial question but doesn't provide me a solution! :o(

Comment: I know that this will probably feel backwards, but the way to set your default email client on OS X is to open up Apple Mail, go to the Preferences, and then select your email client under the "General" tab.  You don't say which version of OS X you're running, but on mine (Mountain Lion 10.8.3), the option for setting your default mail client is the first one under General.

Comment: Thanks for that Nadyne...I will try it. That said I don't run Mail so will have to set it up first. Rather suggests 'Microsoft thinking' to me!

Comment: ... done: set up Mail. Checked preferences and Outlook was already set as default email reader.

Comment: HOLA Tim, thans for disclosing you are using special tools with your email. Since you have answered your original question we can close this discussion to avoid confusion. The new question should contain all relevant information.

Comment: I would sugest your question to be: Outlook Paste function. I paste copied/cut text (from within the same email) it will not paste at the the cursor/ibar but at the top of the email text...I use an automator script and keyboard shortcut to attach pdfs to emails since I've not been able to find a way to change the default email programme that OSX uses for the 'attach to email'. (This was created using the Apple automator and an Outlook library). It seems that when the resulting email is edited the paste function is upset as described above.

Comment: Thank you borderline - an accurate summary. Indeed I had wanted to 'answer' my own question but as a new member I am unable to do that. Given that I have narrowed the issue to something more manageable I am happy for a moderator to close this thread. Thank you all. Impressed by the site by the way. I shall be using it more.